# Django - Chaining Relationship

Tags: django

I have one "Profile" model that belongs to a User, this "Profile" model has some "Groups" and every Group has its own set of "Permissions".

I need to get all Permissions from a User. these are my models:

```
class Perfil(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
    grupo = models.ManyToManyField(Grupo, null=True, blank=True)


class Grupo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    ...
    permisos = models.ManyToManyField(Permiso,null=True,blank=True)


class Permiso(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

I have tried something like this with no success:

```
def obtener_permisos(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        grupos = Grupo.objects.filter(perfil__usuario__username=request.user.username)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            permisos = Permiso.objects.all()
        else:
            permisos = Permiso.objects.filter(grupo__in=grupos).distinct()
        return permisos
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to query the groups separately; you can do it in the query itself.

```
permisos = Permiso.objects.filter(grupo__perfil__usuario=request.user)
```